# joomla 1.0 administrator cant login due to invalid session

Tags: session, joomla, easyphp

I am using joomla 1.0 for developing a website,I cant login at backend (login only at backend).it shows the error messages as follows

first it shows the following errors in administrator/index.php

**first stage**

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/hsphere/local/home/mdlglobe/mdlglobe.com/sessions\sess_972fdf60f45c091916639d797a8c7458, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in E:\EasyPHP 3.0\www\mdlglobe\administrator\index.php on line 111


Warning: session_write_close() [function.session-write-close]: open(/hsphere/local/home/mdlglobe/mdlglobe.com/sessions\sess_972fdf60f45c091916639d797a8c7458, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in E:\EasyPHP 3.0\www\mdlglobe\administrator\index.php on line 150


Warning: session_write_close() [function.session-write-close]: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/hsphere/local/home/mdlglobe/mdlglobe.com/sessions) in E:\EasyPHP 3.0\www\mdlglobe\administrator\index.php on line 150
```

then it redirect to index2.php,and shows

**second stage**

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/hsphere/local/home/mdlglobe/mdlglobe.com/sessions\sess_a1d4a8fb0750e8d835ed4ff59cc4e707, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in E:\EasyPHP 3.0\www\mdlglobe\administrator\index2.php on line 37
```

after that it redirect to the index page itself and show

**third stage**

```
Invalid Session 
 login failed
```

I have searched lot and they says the error occurs due to **session.save_path**

Please anyone tell me how this **session.save_path** edited in **easyphp** and solve this problem .I am facing big issues due to this

As one answer says i have changed session.save_path="E:/easyphp/temp/" But it not effected at all..

Please help

Comment: Why on earth would you use Joomla 1.0 for anything? You should seriously consider using something that is being actively developed. Joomla 2.5 released a couple days ago, that would be a good start.

Comment: because my client stricltly need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I have Solved this issue,by done the following

I changed the **session.save_path** in php.ini

```
session.save_path = "absolute path to the temp folder"
```

Also I have changed the session path in **.htaccess file in the sessions** folder of joomla 1.0

Joomla 1.0 is using differnt method to save session variables than other joomla versions

Answer (score 2):

Check session.save_path in php.ini, it should be like

```
session.save_path = "C:\php\temp"
```

and DIR path should be valid

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You mean set the session.save_path to the temp folder where the easyphp installed.I tried but no change for the errors